# How to open a .exe (not the windows command line) file and send commands to it?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to open an executable file and would like to send commands to it after opening that command line of that specific program. I would like to write a python script for it. Sorry but I am a newbie in to python.

I have tried to open up that executable file by subprocess and I am able to do it however, I am not sure how to send commands to it. I will share my code as well.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(r"C\Dpcmd.exe", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("dpcmd")
```

I did some research and the command which should be sent, should be dpcmd, right?

But this is the error which is showing if I run it through my windows command line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dpcmd.py", line 4, in <module>
p.communicate("dpcmd")
File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 924, in communicate
self._stdin_write(input)
File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 873, in _stdin_write
self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Probably `p.communicate(b"dpcmd")`.

Comment: when I run it then I get longer error. It ends with `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` which explains all.

Comment: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(r"C\Dpcmd.exe", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(b"dpcmd")

I have tried this, the error disappears but the command is still not being sent. Because I cannot see anything on the CMD. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could help to say what is `dpcmd.exe` and what it expects. But many programs expects command line to be terminated with a new line, so I would try `p.communicate(b"dpcmd\n")`

Comment: dpcmd is an executable and it is used for flashing purposes. so if I give the commands like "dpcmd -u\n" to the dpcmd.exe it should start some process related to flashing of the boards connected.

so I give this sort of command and it begins flashing of my board: E.g. dpcmd -ubio.bin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the question is about what is documented here: https://www.eltan.com/images/brochures/sf/dp_sf_manual.pdf, where `dpcmd` is documented starting from page 35, it seems to be a regular, non-interactive command-line program.

Some confusion may come from the usage alternatives

> DediProg window dos command line software is executed by the file “dpcmd.exe.” There
>   are three different ways to run the dos command line.
>
> 1. Double click on the “dpcmd” icon on your desktop and type in dpcmd and enter.
> 2. Change your dos directory to the same location where “dpcmd.exe” is located.
>      C:\program files\dediprog\SF100
> 3. Type in the following command to auto directs the dpcmd command to the “dpcmd.exe”
>      location.
>      Set path=%path%;”c:\program files\dediprog\SF100

where the first alternative suggest there is an icon on your desktop called "dpcmd", but that is presumably just doing what the third alternative, setting up a command prompt where `dpcmd.exe` is in the search path.

Based on alternative 2, the program itself does not depend on being in the path, and thus you should be able to start your flashing task as

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("\"c:\\program files\\dediprog\\SF100\\dpcmd.exe\" -u\"c:\\<path to bio.bin>\\bio.bin\"")
```

or with a bit less surrounding quotation marks when command line is built from a list:

```
p = Popen(["c:\\program files\\dediprog\\SF100\\dpcmd.exe","-uc:\\<path to bio.bin>\\bio.bin"])
```

`Popen` changes the current directory to the directory of the executable, that is why the complete path to `bio.bin` is needed (in both cases).